# Why is the 'join <site>" banner not centred anymore?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I've been browsing through popular questions today when I noticed this banner has shifted placements:

[image]

I'm on a very very very (2560px) wide screen using the latest version of Chrome on OSX Sierra.

I'm not a designer, but I remember this being centred and frankly, I really dislike this new placement. It occured around the same time the new itemprop scheme got released.

[image]
(Google's search screen).

Original behavior still works on the question overview page:

[image]

Comment: we (actually it was me) broke something by mistake.. fix is coming.